# SVG image vs. SVG embed

Tags: html, svg

I store icons in SVG (because of quality). I would like to know which way is better:

1. Put SVG as image `<img src="icon.svg">`
2. Put right in html `<svg>... </svg>`

Sometimes it's complicated shapes. For example Android icon:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M5,8.978c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2v8c0,1.104,0.896,2,2,2s2-0.896,2-2v-8C7,9.873,6.104,8.978,5,8.978z" fill="#85C808"/>
<path d="M27,8.978c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2v8c0,1.104,0.896,2,2,2s2-0.896,2-2v-8C29,9.873,28.104,8.978,27,8.978z" fill="#85C808"/>
<path d="M8,24.978h2v5c0,1.104,0.896,2,2,2s2-0.896,2-2v-5h4v5c0,1.104,0.896,2,2,2s2-0.896,2-2v-5h2v-15H8V24.978z" fill="#85C808"/>
<path d="M20.723,2.53l1.027-1.779c0.139-0.24,0.057-0.545-0.184-0.684c-0.238-0.139-0.545-0.057-0.683,0.184 l-1.001,1.734C18.732,1.345,17.41,0.978,16,0.978c-1.409,0-2.731,0.367-3.882,1.008L11.116,0.25   c-0.139-0.239-0.443-0.321-0.684-0.183c-0.238,0.138-0.32,0.443-0.183,0.683l1.028,1.78C9.294,3.986,8,6.328,8,8.978h16   C24,6.328,22.706,3.986,20.723,2.53z M13,5.978c-0.553,0-1-0.447-1-1s0.447-1,1-1s1,0.447,1,1S13.553,5.978,13,5.978z M19,5.978   c-0.553,0-1-0.447-1-1s0.447-1,1-1s1,0.447,1,1S19.553,5.978,19,5.978z" fill="#85C808"/>
</svg>
```

In the first case, we reduced number of http requests. In the second case, browser render relatively complicated svg. Or does browser render it in the first case? Or can browser cache it for next times?

Any ideas?

Comment: The browser always renders the svg markup, what other component should do that? An image tag always means an additional request, though it is actually possible to cache that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is complex, my advice is not to embed it, the same way we usually don't embed a CSS stylesheet. This way the browser can cache the image so it is used later.

If the image is very simple, my advice is to embed it, since the HTTP request overhead would be bigger than just downloading the image.

Comment: But on the other hand that means an additional http request.

Comment: If two pages containing a complex SVG image are visited, then would you make one more http request or would you download the image again?

Comment: The thing is the "if" in your statement. A definite answer is not possible for this question, since the advantages and disadvantages completely depend on the specific situation. Yet you made a statement that clearly says: do that. _Why?_

Comment: Thank you, edited.

Comment: Good point about a rendering every time complex svg. Thanks.